# Endless directory recursion in IntelliJ IDEA 15

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, project

Directory target/test-classes keeps cascading on every build (see image below). I created the project as "maven". I guess there is something wrong with project settings but I can't find out what.

Paths configured for module:
Output path: E:\data\selenium-java\ShmetsyServer\target\classes
Test output path: E:\data\selenium-java\ShmetsyServer\target\test-classes
[v] exclude output paths (checked)

There are no tests (yet) in this project. 
Also I notice src/tests directory is missing (it was there when I created the project). I probably deleted it by mistake. I created src/tests/java and src/tests/resources again, but target/test-classes/target still gets filled with recursion.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a strange thing on your screenshot. You can try open project structure (`Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S`), go to `Modules` tab and check if your `target` directory marked only as `Excluded`. If this directory marked as something else you should remove these marks.

Also project root folder should not be marked with any option.

Comment: :) strange. I marked project route as "test sources" by mistake. Shouldn't there be some kind of check to find these kind of problems?

Comment: ok. removed "test sources" mark from root and now test classes only contains test classes. thanks!!!! I knew it was strange to have 1 minute build time. Don't ask me how I deleted those 1000s recursive folders...

Comment: Well you can report a bug in IntelliJ bug tracker :) Glad it helped!